# Instance generation with unexported fields. database/sql.Row

Tags: go, sqlx

I have a challenging SWE issue regarding the [sql.Row](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row) of `database/sql` package.

I have the following interface:

```
type SqlQuerier interface {
    QueryRowContext(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row
}
```

The `SqlQuerier` is an interface that has the `QueryRowContext` function signature. That function is implemented by various sql db clients, like [Tx](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Tx.QueryRowContext), [SQLite3](https://github.com/knqyf263/go-rpmdb/blob/master/pkg/sqlite3/sqlite3.go).

I have my own type:

```
func (db *XDB) QueryRowContext(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row {
     // operation
     // check if the operation is successful, if not return error
     // otherwise return sql.Row result
     return db.innerDB.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...)
}
```

`XDB` is an infrastructure wrapper to [sqlx.DB](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB) (`db.innerDB`) which in case the first operation was successful calls its own implementation of `QueryRowContext`.

My issue is that I can't implant Error inside a `sql.Row` result because:

- There isn't a factory function like `NewRow` or setters/getters to its unexported fields.
- Returning `nil` isn't a quite good habit and don't have a quite indicator about the error reason.
- Returning an empty `sql.Row{}` struct is problematic since it'll panic when trying to Scan its values afterwards [.Scan(...)](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Scan).
- Can't set values to unexported fields via reflection.
- Another limitation is that I can't change the function signature to return `(*sql.Row, error)`, because of its various dependencies on the other clients.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Returning `(*sql.Row, error)` is the only correct solution. If you cannot change the function signature, you cannot handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat - this is ugly, and not ideal, and I would personally figure out a different way, but you *could* implement a convention where if the last argument you pass is a `*error`, you set the error it points to be the error you care about

```
    func (db *XDB) QueryRowContext(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row {
        last := args[len(args)-1]
        argsErr, hasArgsErr := last.(*error)
        if hasArgsErr {
            args = args[:len(args)-1]
        }
        // operation
        // check if the operation is successful, if not return error
        // otherwise return sql.Row result
        if (err != nil && hasArgsErr) {
            (*argsErr) = err
        }
        return db.innerDB.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...)
    }
```

and then you can do

```
var queryRowErr error
row := xdb.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, arg1, arg2, &queryRowErr)
if queryRowErr != nil {
    // do something with the error
}
```